# Integrating Facebook & Google login on iOS react-native - AppDelegate.m callback function

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, react-native, google-signin

There are two aspects of the problem of integrating both google & facebook login within AppDelegate.m:

I. Handling the opening conditionally, which I managed via the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

  NSString *stringURL = [ url absoluteString];

  if([stringURL containsString:@"fb"])
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                        openURL:url
                                              sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                     annotation:annotation];
  else return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                           sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                         annotation:annotation];

}
```

II. Handling the callback after user has logged in.
This, I was unable to do with both working simultaneously. Either one or the other gets disabled.
The code snippets for them are as follows:

```
// Facebook SDK
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

// Google 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
  BOOL handled = [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                                     sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                            annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
  return handled;
}
```

If I delete the last part Facebook callback works. 
But I really want both to work :) 
Can someone help?

Comment: you can check that Which URL scheme is calling. So if URL scheme of facebook then it will return from facebook or google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check like this

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

for handling FACEBOOK

```
#pragma -mark
#pragma -mark FACEBOOK Sign-In configuration

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                  openURL:url
                                                        sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                               annotation:annotation
                    ];
    // Add any custom logic here.

    return handled;
}



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
                openURL:(NSURL *)url
                options:(NSDictionary *)options {


    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"fb*************"]) {
        return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app
                                                              openURL:url
                                                    sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                           annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];

    }else
    {

        return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                                   sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                          annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wait for 5 mintues, I will with my answer

Comment: @MartinChristov check my answer

Comment: I already return this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

As for the other part, my code currently looks like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3p3ahax53qwt8bx/Screenshot%202017-08-28%2009.16.10.png?dl=0

So I'm not sure how would you have me modify that function.

Comment: I believe the openURL handler is already doing what you are suggesting.

Comment: you know Facebook have made their custom method to returning to our application. So we need to put that method for Facebook login. For google they use their method so we put method of it. But as per methods they are conflicting with each other that's why I put condition whether it returning from facebook or google. So If you want to work for both then you have to write both conditions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152994/discussion-between-martin-christov-and-jitendra-modi).

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
       sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
        annotation:(id)annotation {

       if ([FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication])
       return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate 
       sharedInstance]application:application openURL:url 
       sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];

      else{

      return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                           sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                  annotation:annotation];
      }
      }
```

Comment: This handler is not for the callback.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

source: https://github.com/facebookarchive/react-native-fbsdk/issues/770

You have to modify openUrl function at appdelegate.m

Code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  if ([[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                      openURL:url
                                                      options:options]) {
     return YES;
  }
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}
```